# Grouping / editting png file in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have a menu that was sent to me as a png file. I am trying to edit it with illustrator. I need to move and resize the logo.  I also need to group each menu item with its description and the background items so i can move them around and resize them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask for the correct file or re-draw it again.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you can't.

Illustrator is for working with vector images, not flattened raster ones, such as a PNG. You can open the PNG in Photoshop and then make some edits that way, but even with a flattened image, the edits you can make will be very limited.  Get your hands on the PSD or another layered file, if you can.